# Julia - Using JuMP Triangular Matrix Variables in JuMP causes bad type performance

Tags: performance, variables, julia, sparse-matrix, julia-jump

On the next MWE, `@code_warntype` returns bad performance type, `##1469::JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray`.

```
using JuMP, Gurobi
function MWE(n)
      m = Model(Gurobi.Optimizer)
      @variable(m, x[i=1:n, j=i+1:n], Bin)
      @variable(m, y[i=1:n], Bin)
end
@codewarn_type MWE(5)
```

While the adapted version where `j` goes from 1 to n instead of i+1 to n is totally great for `@codewarn_type`.

```
function MWE_codewarntype_safe(n)
       m = Model(Gurobi.Optimizer)
       @variable(m, x[i=1:n, j=1:n], Bin)
       @variable(m, y[i=1:n], Bin)
end
@codewarn_type MWE(5)
```

However, I can't allow my model to have nearly twice more variables and more than half unused. I ran both code with larger instances and the performances quickly deteriorate. Does this mean I should ignore what @code_warntype tells? If so, that's not the first time I would have to ignore it and I find it particularly unclear how to understand when @codewarn_type returns are meaningful. Maybe I should ask a more general question about this macro, how to read and understand it?

Comment: I would go with twice more variables and give constraints assigning their values to 0. When Solver goes through it, it will auto-magically remove those variables from the model anyway so the optimization time should not be affected.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel, thanks! This is indeed faster :) Yet I'm surprise this is how one should code, adding "useless" variables forced to be zero :) You can add an answer and i'll select it if it's the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. I thought we fixed this. Note that `x` is a concrete type, so this is just a failure of Julia's inference. It also means that when `x` is passed to another function (e.g., `add_constraint`), it will be fast.

Edit: opened an issue to discuss: https://github.com/jump-dev/JuMP.jl/issues/2457

Here's the MWE:

```
using JuMP
function MWE(n)
    model = Model()
    @variable(model, x[i=1:n, j=i+1:n])
end
@code_warntype MWE(5)
```

The question to ask is: is the time difference material? If it's only marginally faster, I would go with the more readable version.